# How to interpret compiler messages 'Couldn't match type: [b0] with: [a2] -> t :'?

Tags: haskell

I am learning the basic of Haskell and have trouble understanding compiler messages, that is how do types from the error messages correspond to the types from the expression.

If I intentionally give the compiler the wrong expression

```
sum map (+1) [1,2,3]   -- this is wrong on purpose to trigger a
                       -- compiler error
```

instead of the correct

```
sum (map (+1) [1,2,3])
```

then I would like to understand what the compiler output means.

For example:

```
:t sum map (+1) [1,2,3]
```

```
<interactive>:1:5: error:
    • Couldn't match type: [b0]
                     with: [a2] -> t
      Expected: (a0 -> b0) -> (a1 -> a1) -> [a2] -> t
        Actual: (a0 -> b0) -> [a0] -> [b0]
    • In the first argument of ‘sum’, namely ‘map’
      In the expression: sum map (+ 1) [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: `f x y z` calls `f` with three arguments. Similarly, `sum map (+1) [1,2,3]` calls `sum` with three arguments. You need parentheses `sum (map (+1) [1,2,3])`.

Comment: I have updated your question to make it more clear that you know that the expression is wrong but you want to learn how to read the compiler/interpreter output. If you don't like my rewrite you can revert to your old question by clicking on the history and undoing my changes. Let me know if you need help with that if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for editing, it became much more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to apply `sum` to the result of all the rest, so you need either parenthesis,

```hs
sum (map (+1) [1,2,3])
```

or [a `$`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36-) which evaluates its rhs first before passing it to the lhs:

```hs
sum $ map (+1) [1,2,3]
```

The way you've written it, you're applying `sum` to `map`, just as you had written `(sum map) (+1) [1,2,3]`, which doesn't make sense.

---

The error is simply telling you what there's an error

```
    • In the first argument of ‘sum’, namely ‘map’
```

which (`map`) has the `Actual` type `(a0 -> b0) -> [a0] -> [b0]` whereas the only way the compiler could make sense of the whole expression is if you had passed, instead of `map`, an entity of the `Expected` type `(a0 -> b0) -> (a1 -> a1) -> [a2] -> t`.

That expected type is simply a consequence of the further aruments you've passed to `sum map`. Indeed, `sum map` by itself is "fine", in the sense that it could in principle make sense. It's type is

```
:: (Foldable ((->) (a -> b)), Num ([a] -> [b])) => [a] -> [b]
```

where you can already see the absurdity of expecting a `[a] -> [b]` which is an instance of `Num`.

But that's ok, because the types are still polymorphic, not constrained enough for the compiler to work out that thing can't work.

At the moment you pass some types which have almost an exact type such as `[1,2,3]`, which is a `Num a => [a]`, and `(+1)`, which is `Num a => a -> a`, then the compiler can't make head or tail of it, and tells you that.

---

Your question, in some way, could be rephrased as

> Why the type of `x` in `\x -> sum x (+1) [1,2,3]` is `(Foldable t1, Num a1, Num a2, Num ((a1 -> a1) -> [a2] -> t2)) => t1 ((a1 -> a1) -> [a2] -> t2)`?

And the answer is again is that that is as much as the compiler can do to try making types check.

---

Also, look at this example,

```hs
sum (:) (+1) [1,2,3]
```

where I'm passing `(:)` instead of `map`. The error is slightly different:

```
<interactive>:37:5: error:
    • Couldn't match type: [a0]
                     with: [a2] -> t
      Expected: a0 -> (a1 -> a1) -> [a2] -> t
        Actual: a0 -> [a0] -> [a0]
    • In the first argument of ‘sum’, namely ‘(:)’
      In the expression: sum (:) (+ 1) [1, 2, 3]
```

See how it compares to yours:

```
<interactive>:1:5: error:
    • Couldn't match type: [b0]
                     with: [a2] -> t
      Expected: (a0 -> b0) -> (a1 -> a1) -> [a2] -> t
        Actual: (a0 -> b0) -> [a0] -> [b0]
    • In the first argument of ‘sum’, namely ‘map’
      In the expression: sum map (+ 1) [1, 2, 3]
```

In your example the compiler expected `(a0 -> b0) -> (a1 -> a1) -> [a2] -> t`, whereas in my example it expected `a0 -> (a1 -> a1) -> [a2] -> t`. So was the compiler expecting different things?! Are those types truly different?

```
(a0 -> b0) -> (a1 -> a1) -> [a2] -> t
a0         -> (a1 -> a1) -> [a2] -> t
```

No, it's just that the former is restricted to take a first argument of type `a0 -> b0`, i.e. a function, whereas the latter can accept any `a0`, i.e. functions plus non functions.

And that's a consequence of the fact that you you passed `map` which is a less generic type, `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, and I passed `(:)` which is a bit more generic, `a -> [a] -> [a]`, so the former ended up constraining the expected signature of the first argument to `sum` a bit more, i.e. `(a0 -> b0)` instead of `a0`.

Comment: It's getting clearer now, but I would like to elabore more on the expected type:

`(a0 -> b0) -> (a1 -> a1) -> [a2] -> t`

Is it so, that in this type expression `(a1 -> a1)` corresponds to `(+1)`, `[a2]` to `[1,2,3]`, `t` is the output type of sum function?

And is `(a0 -> b0)` the type of the expression which should be used instead of map to satisfy the whole expression?
What an example of such a function can be, which we could use here as an example?

Comment: @AlexSchell, no, the type of the expression that "should" be used in place of  `map` is what the compiler is telling you is the expected type, `(a0 -> b0) -> (a1 -> a1) -> [a2] -> t`. I've given another example where the compiler seems to expect a different type. In reality that's not the case. Think of it this way: the compiler is trying to resolve a system of algebraic equations which has no solution. It tries to do it, gets to a contraddiction after all the simplification it can do, and tells you what doesn't fit.

Comment: thank you very much for explanations.
But what I still cannot fully understand - the expected type `(a0 -> b0) -> (a1 -> a1) -> [a2] -> t` nevertheless corresponds to the whole expression type `sum map (+1) [1,2,3]` ? Because expected type ends with t, what corresponds to the polymorphic  scalar, i.e. the result of the sum fuction, and [a2] is the list what sum expects.
It is not that the expected type looks like this? `sum ((a0 -> b0) -> (a1 -> a1) -> [a2] -> t) (+1) [1,2,3]`. If it is true, it is not clear from where intermediate steps (a1 -> b1) and others are coming from.

Comment: No, the error is clear in telling you that `(a0 -> b0) -> (a1 -> a1) -> [a2] -> t` is the expected type for **the first argument of ‘sum’**, not of the whole expression.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations and patience.